# Fading in different items and different times using Greensock Tween

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am really new with **GSAP** and I think it is amazing. However I cannot work out how to fade in these items separately.

1st one (this is fine) for the 2nd wish to fade in at a certain time and 3rd at a certain time.

**JavaScript:**

```
function startFinalAnimation(){
    var fa = new TimelineLite();
    fa.to(finalAvatar, 2, {scale: 0.45, delay: 0, opacity: 1, transformOrigin:"-3% 8.8%"});
    fa.to(finalContent, 4, {delay: 0, opacity: 1});
    fa.to(logo, 5, {delay: 0, opacity: 1});
}
```

Comment: You could add name to each animation and set delay uppon to it http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/

Comment: Also, I recommend you to watch their video example - http://greensock.com/sequence-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`TimelineLite`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/)**'s [.to()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/to/) method syntax is as follows:

```
timeline.to(target, duration, vars, position);
```

This fourth `position` parameter is something you can use to exactly position wherever you want your tween to appear. So you could, for example, do:

```
function startFinalAnimation(){
    var fa = new TimelineLite();
    fa.to(finalAvatar, 2, { scale: 0.45, opacity: 1, transformOrigin:"-3% 8.8%" });
    fa.to(finalContent, 4, { opacity: 1 }, '-=1');
    fa.to(logo, 5, { opacity: 1 }, '-=2');
}
```

Here, `-=1` (and `-=2`) basically tell that the animation should be added at an overlap of `1` second onto the previous animation's end, instead of the default which is to append at the very end of previously added animation.

There are many ways a `position` can be provided. Above, I used `-=`. Other options are (taken from the link provided below):

> - at an absolute time (1).
> - relative to the end of a timeline allowing for gaps ("+=1") or overlaps ("-=1").
> - at a label ("someLabel").
> - relative to a label ("someLabel+=1").

Read more about the `position` parameter here: [Timeline Tip: Understanding the Position Parameter](http://greensock.com/position-parameter).

Comment: It did not seem to work, just all happens at the same time.

Comment: can you prepare a quick fiddle please?

Comment: you needed initial variables to be set first, before you can reach the destination variables. `TimelineLite`'s **[`.fromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/fromTo/)** method can help you with that.

Comment: Another way of approaching the same problem of setting values first would be: **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/a4y97pvb/)**.

Comment: you may want to share a fiddle with your entirety of your content perhaps :)

Comment: Its all too large and complicated with all the other code, i was firing the function twice so thats why that was happening.  However it does seem to show the finalContent when load the page then fades out and back in on that timer... ill have a look to see if anything else is causing it but thought would of been hiding to start with right?

Comment: also is there anyway to delay the start of the first animation, so hold for a few seconds before the transformOrigin kicks in?

Comment: you can delay the whole timeline sequence by adding the `delay` parameter to the constructor of `TimelineLite` object like so: `... = new TimelineLite({ delay: xxx });`.

Comment: or you could add delays to individual tweens as well, like what you have in your question.

Comment: you have a timer in there as well? I am curious as to what approach you have here.

Comment: Its ok managed to sort it out :) thanks for all your help again.

Comment: glad you did. no worries.